# How to run multiple servlets execution in parallel for Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, concurrency

I have a Tomcat application, I need two different servlets or the same one to respond in parallel to my requests. The case is I have a first request asking to download medical imaging and I have another AJAX client request fetching images before the first request is completely done. But for some reason, the server does not respond to my second request until the first one is over.

What has to be changed in order to achieve concurrent servlets execution? We have a pretty good server with multiple drives, multiple cores. I'm using Tomcat 6. Any ideas to explore would be great.

Comment: Do you use any resource that has exclusive access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that happens it's not about Tomcat. Probably you're using synchronization (implicitly or explicitly) somewhere.

However you can manage thread-pooling expicitly:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

or

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

I.e. you can either specify the number of max threads or use a thread-pool. More information here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: My first request has to access a third party server to retrieve images. My second request comes to a different servlet and only need to read the stuff the first servlet is writing. How can I find who is locking everything up?

Comment: So the first servlet is writing data, while the second one is trying to read it? I believe that is the key. What are you using to read-write the data?

Comment: The first servlet has incoming files, once written I suppose they are not locked or anything. The second tries to read the files and if it fails (because of file lock) it will try again after 1 sec. But what I see it the second request halts until the first is over. That's why I was wondering about Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat doesn't block threads itself. Definitely the issue is outside Tomcat. What classes are you exactly using for file IO operations? If there is custom code - can you inspect it or post it here?

Comment: I thought a new request hitting a servlet would create a new thread to server the request. How come all is blocked?

Comment: It DOES create a new thread (to be precise it re-uses a thread from a thread-pool). Again - post some code here (with IO operations) so it will be easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I just need confirmation Tomcat can handle requests by itself. Now I'll try to investigate further. regards.

Comment: OK. Tomcat can handle threads and uses different threads for different requests. You can rely on this 100%. See my answer update.