# What happens if I give a large value to server.tomcat.max-threads to handle load on my application?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

There are around `1000+ jobs running through our service in a day and around 70-80 jobs starting at the same time and running parallelly`.

To handle this, we looked that increasing the number of max threads to a large number to `server.tomcat.max-threads` property of our Spring application should work but I do not have full confidence as to what all can be the side effects of having a huge number like `800` to this property.

Can you please help here.

Comment: That property won't help as that is for request handling threads.

Answer (score 0):

The default installation of Tomcat sets the maximum number of HTTP servicing threads at 200. Effectively, this means that the system can handle a maximum of 200 simultaneous HTTP requests. When the number of simultaneous HTTP requests exceeds this count, the unhandled requests are placed in a queue, and the requests in this queue are serviced as processing threads become available. This default queue length is 100. At these default settings, a large web load that can generate over 300 simultaneous requests will surpass the thread availability, resulting in service unavailable (HTTP 503).

More reference: https://docs.bmc.com/docs/brid91/en/tomcat-container-workload-configuration-825210082.html

[How to run multiple servlets execution in parallel for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183484/how-to-run-multiple-servlets-execution-in-parallel-for-tomcat)

If this is a batch job like configuration, you can use spring batch.